# Does $(\pm 3, \pm 4)$ refer to 2 points or 4?

Tags: notation, convention

I've seen the notation $\mp$ to contrast with $\pm$ to indicate "Yes there are only two cases and these guys must be opposite signs".  So something like $(\pm2, \mp3)$ would just be $\{(2, -3), (-2, 3) \}$.  But if I write $(\pm 3, \pm 4)$, does this refer to $\{(3,4), (-3, -4)\}$, or $\{(3,4), (-3, -4), (3, -4), (-3, 4)\}$?

Comment: $(\pm a, \pm b)$ is not preferred due to the very reason you are asking the question.

Comment: As you note, the notation is ambiguous, and either interpretation could be justified.  If you are seeing this in a text, look for context that can clarify.  If this is in your own writing, use better notation.

Comment: This is my own writing, and I'm desiring the four points interpretation.  Is there a way to clarify this without writing out all the points?

Comment: I agree the notation is ambiguous.  Since $\pm (2,3)$ would obviously mean $(2,3), (-2,-3)$ I would argue that $(\pm 2, \pm 3)$ should mean four points, but it would be best to spell that out.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I would probably write out all four points, or at least write $(3,\pm 4), (-3,\pm 4)$.  If you wrote "The four points $(\pm 3, \pm 4)$," that might also be clear enough to get the job done.  You could also write something like $\{ ((-1)^m\cdot 3, (-1)^n\cdot 4) : m,n\in\mathbb{Z} \}$, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score -1):

This is obviously an abbreviation of four-point writing. For example we can write that the only solution in integers of the system

$$\begin{cases}x^4+y^4=17\\x\lt y\end{cases}$$ is given by $(x,y)=(\pm1,\pm2)$.

Comment: As per the comments, it seems like alot of people do not find this clear.  What do you think?

Comment: Finding something in mathematics clear or not depends on people. For me it is evident but I understand that it is not so clear for someone else. By the way, I must say that in the example I put there is what the French call "abus de langage" because it does not express a solution but four. But those "abuses of language" are not uncommon in mathematics (they are tolerated when one is aware that what is said is not strictly formal).

Comment: MSE should prohibit downvotes are made without exposing reasons. There are bitter beings and homunculous  in the world.