How to deal with multiple plus-or-minus signs (±) in a single expression
When you have a single plus-or-minus symbol, the meaning is clear:
$a±b = (a+b) OR (a-b)$
When you have plus-or-minus and minus-or-plus symbols, the meaning is also clear, as described in many places, such as this post (https://math.stackexchange.com/a/160479/1238228):
$a±b∓c = (a+b-c) OR (a-b+c)$
Here's my question, what is the meaning when you have multiple plus-or-minus symbols? I see two possible potential meanings, as described in the following two expressions:

$a±b±c = (a+b+c) OR (a-b-c)$
$a±b±c = (a+b+c) OR (a+b-c) OR (a-b+c) OR (a-b-c)$

If multiple plus-or-minus symbols mean that all symbols take the same sign (as shown in the first potential meaning), there should be a way to clearly indicate the behavior shown in the second potential meaning (and visa versa).
Technically, there is a way to clearly show the first potential meaning:
$a±b∓(-c) = (a+b-(-c)) OR (a-b+(-c)) = (a+b+c) OR (a-b-c)$
However, this way is clunky, and there should be another way to write this.

I think the simplest option is to just clarify in words whether the signs are independent or not.

Symbols in math (and not only) are used to clarifying things: if a formula is so confused that we have to supplement it with a verbal clarification, it means that it is WRONG.

I would say that $a \pm b \pm c$ is ambiguous and should be clarified in the text, since both conventions exist. Some other rules of thumb:

If there is a $\mp$ sign anywhere, all the $\pm$ and $\mp$ should be coordinated.
If there are $\pm$ signs on both sides of an equation then all of them should be coordinated, especially if there's a different number of them on each side.
If you need anything in between "all independent" and "all coordinated", a possibility is to use $\pm_1$, $\pm_2$ and so on, where the same index is used for those that are coordinated. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation#Ferrari's_solution.


+1. I never saw the $\pm_1$ version, and the version $\pm_{s}$ and $\pm_t$ used in the Wikipedia article would confuse me at first. Maybe worth a clarification such as "$\pm_1$ and $\pm_2$ are independent", in which case using $\varepsilon_1$ and $\varepsilon_2$ with $\varepsilon_i$ explicitly defined to be in ${-1,1}$ seems better.

To be fair, the wikipedia article does explain the meaning after each use of that notation. I'm sure I've seen it without explanation somewhere, but can't track down an example.

I think most mathematicians would interpret
$$
a \pm b \pm c
$$
as allowing the four options listed in option (2).
If you want option (1), write
$$
a \pm (b+c).
$$
There is no uniformly accepted convention for multiple $\pm$ and $\mp$ signs. It's the author's responsibility to make the intended meaning clear in any particular context.

Likewise for $x\pm y\mp z$ you could write $x\pm(y-z)$ and have no need for the $\mp$ symbol. And yet we have $\mp.$

@DavidK You need both $\pm$ and $\mp$ when the signs are coordinated in separate places in the expression, as in the trigonometry examples the OP links to.

So the examples in the question and this answer aren't the best examples. Note that in the sine formula in the link we have coordinated $\pm$ signs. In any case, the "convention" is not universally recognized or followed. See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2538374/139123

And in the formula $\sin (x\pm y) = \sin x \cos y \pm \cos x \sin y$ (from the same link) you have coordinated $\pm$ signs. I don't think there's a general rule that covers all cases.

@DavidK Fair points. Best not to rely on any convention when there's potential ambiguity.

Definitely not most mathematicians.

It seems this answer is attracting some downvotes signifying disagreement, which is unfortunate. But this may be a result of the question being featured on the Hot Network Questions list and/or the answer starting by seemingly speaking for "most mathematicians".

I interpret this as
all the $\pm$ represent the same sign,
all the $\mp$ represent the same sign,
and
the $\mp$ is the sign opposite to
$\pm$.
So each such line has
two valid interpretations:
(1) $\pm$ means $+$ and $\mp$ means $-$;
(2) $\pm$ means $-$ and $\mp$ means $+$.

I think the convention is that several $\pm$ signs represent independent choices. That's worked wherever I encountered them.

@EthanBolker $1/(x\pm 1) = \pm 1 - x \pm x^2 - x^3 \pm x^4 \cdots.$
